# how to check screen height for further $http requests?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Assume a function checking the screen height and make `$http.get` requests until it fills the screen.

```
app.controller('HomeController', function ($scope, $timeout, Api) {
  function checkScreen () {
    $timeout(function() {
      //Firefox fix
      var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
      if (html.scrollTop == 0) {
        html = html.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
      }

      var scrollHeight = html.scrollHeight;
      var clientHeight = document.querySelector('body').clientHeight;
      var fromTime = Date.parse($scope.data[$scope.data.length - 1].value.date);
      if (clientHeight == scrollHeight) {
        $scope.fetcher(fromTime, checkScreen);
      }
    });
  }

  $scope.fetcher(0, checkScreen);
});
```

the fetcher uses Api service for $http requests

```
$scope.fetcher = function (fromTime, callback) {
  Api.post.getList(fromTime).then(function (result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
      $scope.data.push(result.data[i]);
    };
    callback();
  });
}
```

this code has several bad practice issues:

- checks for HTML/CSS properties in controller
- needs initial call for fetcher in the controller
- If I need to call fetcher in a directive (like an infinite scrolling appender), the directive will be tight coupled with controller.

how should I refactor it eliminating these issues? 
**note:** $scope.fetcher is different in each controller but the infinite-scroll directive is common for all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using Api service to create a more specific service named Fetcher is a better solution than using $scope.fetcher in controller. 
this way the direction won't be **tight coupled** with controller anymore.
plus, check the screen as a distinct function of side of AngularJS and use the it's returned Boolean value in controller for multiple using Fetcher service